# Bootstrapping Zend_Application with Zend_Test

Tags: zend-framework, zend-test

in the docs the provided code for bootstrapping looks like

```
protected $application;
public function setUp() {
    $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
    parent::setUp();
}
public function appBootstrap() {
    $this->application = new Zend_Application( ... );
    $this->application->bootstrap();
}
```

i was curious why when i tried

```
protected $application;
public function setUp() {
    $this->application = new Zend_Application( ... );
    $this->application->bootstrap();
    parent::setUp();
}
```

it failed. also when i tried moving bootstrapping the application in bootstrap.php it fails too

```
// bootstrap.php
...
$application = new Zend_Application( ... );
$application->bootstrap();
```

the reason why i thought of moving this to bootstrap.php is [jon lebensold from zend casts](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-with-the-zend-framework-with-zend_test-and-phpunit/2009/06/) extended the ControllerTestCase to handle all this bootstrapping in a separate class. i thought instead of extending the class, if i can move the code into the bootstrap.php in 1 place wont it be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what my ControllerTestCase.php looks like:

```
<?php
abstract class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {

        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }
}
```

TestHelper.php (Bootstrap)

```
<?php
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../public'));
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(BASE_PATH . '/../application'));

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '.',
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path()
)));

define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');

require_once "Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php";

$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
$loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);

require_once 'ControllerTestCase.php';
```